# Convert 3 Address codes in Assembly

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, code-generation

I am trying to convert 3 Address codes in ASSEMBLY code  [Code Generation].

Consider,

[image]

The Assembly code sequence is:

[image]

If order is changed to t2 t3 t1 t4, then

[image]

1. `ADD` is done with Memory operand + Register operand but `SUB` is never done with Memory operand. Similarly, I have seen that `MUL` is also never done with Memory operand. Is there some rule like this ?
2. Why `MOV R0,t1` is used? Isn't it better to use one more Register and keep using `R0`?
3. Bring `t1` down, `t2-t3-t1-t4` is the new sequence and we save instructions *i.e.* we can use the Reg which keeps the value of `t1` immediately in the next instruction. But to use a Register after the immediate instruction we have to store it in memory?

Comment: **Assembly code is dependent on the architecture for which you're writing the code.**
Registers are typically used, because getting r/w operations to particular memory location is more time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, operands have to involve at least one register so you cannot, for example, subtract t1 from t2 directly. Therefore, you have to move op1 to a register and apply the operation to op2 - the result going into the register. In this case, e-t1 *cannot* be used as a register (it's on the wrong side of the operand) whereas t1-e could.

One alternative would be to negate and add t1 which could then be used without resorting to memory. So:

```
mov   a, R0
add   b, R0           ; t1 (R0) := a+b
mov   c, R1
add   d, R1           ; t2 (R1) := c+d
neg   R1
add   e, R1           ; t3 (R1) := e+(-t2)
neg   R1
add   R0, R1          ; t4 (R1) := t1+(-t3)
```